# Python: Str Position?

Tags: python

i am learning from python online course regarding open & read file. Stumble upon one of the code line

`data = "{:^13}  {:<11}  {:<6}\n"`

One of the response obtained as below. However, I am still not clear of the following

1. In the response, it is mentioned `which will come at position of 13 , 11 and 6`

What does it mean by position? is it similar to index?

2. what does the notation `"^", "<" and {:}` represent?
3. why use eg {:^13} instead of str(data.format(rnd10000,9999)

**unclear clarification**

```
Thank you for the post!

data = "{:^13} {:<11} {:<6}\n" this will be printed as string which will be formatted using the random number between 10000 9999 , which will come at position of 13 , 11 and 6

Happy learning!
```

**Code as below**

```
from random import randint as rnd

memReg = 'members.txt'
exReg = 'inactive.txt'
fee =('yes','no')

def genFiles(current,old):
    with open(current,'w+') as writefile: 
        writefile.write('Membership No  Date Joined  Active  \n')
        data = "{:^13}  {:<11}  {:<6}\n"

        for rowno in range(20):
            date = str(rnd(2015,2020))+ '-' + str(rnd(1,12))+'-'+str(rnd(1,25))
            writefile.write(data.format(rnd(10000,99999),date,fee[rnd(0,1)]))
```

Comment: You're basically looking for [Format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) from the Python docs?

Comment: oh okay okay thanks. didnt know about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets try something a little more simple and take it apart step by step, to see why it's happening:

```
data = "{:^13} {:<11} {:<6}\n"
print(data.format(1,2,3))
>>>      1       2           3     

>>>
```

1. The notation ":^" *center-aligns* the value.
2. The notation ":<" *left-aligns* the value.

Can we understand why the string looks like that now? Yes! Absolutely:

```
>>> "{:^13}".format(1)
'      1      '
>>> len('      1      ')
13
```

The first part of the formatted string is 13 characters long with whatever you pass into it - centered (`{:^13}`).

```
>>> "{:<11}".format(2)
'2          '
>>> len('2          ')
11
>>> "{:<6}".format(3)
'3     '
>>> len('3     ')
6
```

The 2nd part of the formatted string is 11 characters long and the 3rd part is 6 characters long because we prepend whitespaces (*note that it does not have to be whitespaces! You can choose the character that will be used for padding by writing it before the `<` sign like this: `{:_<11}` -> now we would prepend `_`*) until we have 11 and 6 characters in the strings respectively.

We can confirm that that is what is happening by counting them together: 13 + 11 + 6 + 2 Whitespaces inbetween brackets + 1 New line = 33

```
>>> len(data.format(1,2,3))
33
```

Okay, so we fully understand why the string got formatted how it did, but now comes your question why use ***this way of formatting*** instead of using ***that way of formatting***. Python does offer a ton of way to format data but when it comes to the string [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) method there is one article that I would recommend to everyone:

> https://pyformat.info/

There you will find a lot of comparisons between old-style formatting methods and the `.format()` method. Not everything is possible with both and even aside from that, there are a lot of differences. I think you should be able to find all of the answers there as well.

Last but not least, [@ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) already provided you the actual [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) with all nuances and details about the formatting "mini-language". While not as beginner friendly, it's a good habit to always read the documentation first when trying to understand how someones code is working.